# Magento display a block without ChildHtml

Tags: magento, layout

I create a simple block (just a core/template) with a custom phtml file to make an extension without modifying other phtml file.

But I cannont make it shows except by modifying an original template to add `$this->getChildHtml('myblock')` thing.

I want to add my block without changing any other phtml. How to do this, how to make the block display automatically without `getChildHtml` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out how to do this,

I create my own module, with my own layout and templates.

In the layout I updated the section where the parent block is called, to insert my new block first, then in my template I call the parent through getChildHtml() so I don't have to touch any of my client's file.

Best regards, to everyone

Answer (score 6):

If your block is of type `core/text_list` or `page/html_wrapper` then it will display all child nodes.See the toHtml() function of the `core/text_list` block: http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php

Answer (score 1):

You can define your block under root block as following:

```
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="core/template" name="custom_block" output="toHtml" template="custom/custom_block.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

The trick is to use output="toHtml" to make your block as an output block, only the output blocks are rendered automatically. It's important to put your block under root since by default theme root block is the only output block that's responsible to render all its child blocks.

For more detail, please take a look at:
http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/digging-deeper-into-magentos-layout-xml-part-2/

Hope this will help someone.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

- Use **core/text** type. These blocks will render itself automatically. However, this method is not suitable when your block use its own class.
- Any block of type **core/text_list** will automatically render all its children. Just make your block is a child of core/text_list.

Check this article for more info - http://nwdthemes.com/2015/05/29/render-layout-block-automatically-in-magento/

Answer (score -1):

Only certain files have the capability of displaying all children nodes.  With that said, the vast majority do not have that capability built in.

You can enable this functionality by added a line to the phtml file that you want to render any block that is attached to it.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

Comment: The user explicitly asked how to do it without using getChildHtml().

Comment: He didn't want to use $this->getChildHtml('block_id').  He wants this to display without modifying the original PHTML which is all fine and dandy.  But you cannot make a PHTML file appear in just any other file unless the $this->getChildHtml('') is already called.  And as I said this happens in VERY few files.  He is looking for this custom block to magically appear.  If there is no $this->getChildHtml() then no amount of layout XML is going to display it in the intended location, period.